# html encoding with php

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have an issue. I have a column in **mysql** database like

```
<p><strong>WELCOME</strong></p>
<p><strong>About Me</strong>
```

Now I want to fetch this in my php page. But when I am fetching, it doesn't show bold text, only normal text.
I am using

```
html_entity_decode($content,0,1649)."...");
```

Comment: Why are you HTML-encoding on storage?

Comment: I agree with @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams and check your encoding types from your database.

Comment: Even if I am using <span style="font-weight:bold"> instead of <strong> tag then it works.

Comment: I removed the htmlentities also now. But still not working. By the way how to check the encoding type in DB and what should be it?

Comment: Might need to know what your CSS is doing.  If it is overwriting or resetting.

Comment: @Daya That is not helpful. The <strong> tag is the correct way of embolding text.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like what is happening is that you have some other code that is escaping your data prior to being output for HTML.

This is a **good thing** in most cases.  You don't want HTML with `<script>` tags and what not being allowed in your data from users.  If anything, you don't want `<` and `>` to be misinterpreted.

However, if you do want to allow HTML, you need to modify whatever is outputting your HTML to not escape this particular variable.